# How can I change control props in a React Vimeo video after video has loaded?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

In a functional component, I have a page where I load an initial video, which is supposed to be a background welcome video to the page, and that video shouldn't have controls on it. However, once the user selected a new video, I want the controls to change. I'm using @u-wave/react-vimeo to display my video. I was thinking that the controls should just update whenever the state changes, but that isn't working for me. How should I hide videos when I want to, and show them when I want to?
My code is as follows:

```
const defaultVimeoId = '1234567890';

const VideoDisplayer = () => {
  const {videoId} = useContext(VideoContext);
  const [video, setVideo] = useState();
  const [vimeoId, setVimeoId] = useState(defaultVimeoId);
  const [isDefault, setIsDefault] = useState(true);
  const [showControls, setShowControls] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (videoId) {
      setShowControls(true);
      setVimeoId(/*Does some magic here to get the vimeo ID of other videos*/);
      setIsDefault(false);
    }
    else {
      setIsDefault(true);
    }
  }, [videoId, isDefault, showControls]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Vimeo
                video={`https://vimeo.com/${vimeoId}`}
                autoplay={isDefault ? true : false}
                loop={isDefault ? true : false}
                muted={isDefault ? true : false}
                background={false}
                controls={showControls}
                style={{width: '100%'}}
                responsive
              />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
  
export default VideoDisplayer;
```

Whenever I click on a video and the context of the vimeo ID changes, the new video loads, but it won't let me change the control visibility this way. Any ideas here?

Comment: Are you a paying vimeo customer? Theres quite a lot of constraints around the controls visibility thing.

Comment: @adamThomas I am, and if I set controls to true, it will work, and when I set controls to false, it will work. But when I update that state Boolean, it doesn’t then show or hide controls